# Convert to Bibi-binary

Tags: code-golf, conversion, hexadecimal

Bibi-binary is a numeric system invented by [Boby Lapointe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boby_Lapointe) in order to represent numbers in letters which pronunciation seems funny.

Your task is to convert decimal numbers into Bibi-binary!

### Conversion

A number is converted to base 16 (hexadecimal) and each character is replaced by its Bibi-binary name:

```
0 = HO
1 = HA
2 = HE
3 = HI
4 = BO
5 = BA
6 = BE
7 = BI
8 = KO
9 = KA
A = KE
B = KI
C = DO
D = DA
E = DE
F = DI
```

Let `N` be a positive integer (between 1 -> 2^31-1).
For every character in the hexadecimal representation of `N`, replace the character by its according Bibi-binary pair (the table above contains all the pairs).

### Example

- `N` = 156
- `H` = (hexadecimal representation of `N`) --> 9C
- 9 --> KA, C --> DO

Thus the output is KADO.

### Input & output

You will receive an positive 32-bit integer `N`, which you will have to turn into Bibi-binary.

You may (return, print, etc...) in any convenient format, **but the pairs have to be connected**! So `KA DO` wouldn't be okay, but `KADO` would.

Both, **lowercase and uppercase** are allowed.

### Rules

- No loopholes.
- This is code-golf, so the shortest code wins.

### Testcases

```
2048 -> KOHOHO
156 -> KADO
10000 -> HEBIHAHO
12 -> DO
```

Comment: The spec seems to say that the input will be non-negative in one section and positive in another - could you please clarify which one is intended?

Comment: @Sp3000 positive is intended. I'll edit that in, thanks!

Comment: Your spec still says *between 0 -> 2^31-1*, but **0** isn't positive (in English).

Comment: @Dennis I treated 0 as positive. I'll edit that out. Thanks for the mention!

Comment: @TuukkaX **0** is precisely the distinction between positive and non-negative.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>20</s> <s>18</s> 16 bytes

```
hv…Ã‚kdžM¨ÁâyHèJ
```

**Explanation**

```
h                     # convert input to hex
 v                    # for each
  …Ã‚kd               # string of the possible first Bibi-binary letters
       žM¨Á           # string of the possible second Bibi-binary letters
           â          # cartesian product to produce list of Bibi-binary pairs
            yH        # convert hex char to base 10
              è       # use this to index into the list
               J      # join
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=aHbigKbDg-KAmmtkxb5NwqjDgcOieUjDqEo&input=MTAwMDA)

Saved 2 bytes thanks to [Adnan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/34388/adnan)

Comment: `…Ã‚kd` is a compressed version of `"hbkd"` :).

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if it's possible but `H` also converts a hexadecimal number to base 10.

Answer (score 12):

## Python 2, 58 bytes

```py
f=lambda n:(n>15and f(n/16)or"")+"HBKD"[n/4%4]+"OAEI"[n%4]
```

A recursive solution. [Try it on Ideone](http://ideone.com/pe889f).

Comment: `f=lambda n:n*'_'and f(n/16)+"HBKD"[n/4%4]+"OAEI"[n%4]` saves 5 bytes.

Comment: I undeleted my comment. The OP clarified and input **0** is invalid.

Answer (score 4):

## Python 2, <s>81</s> 76 bytes

```py
lambda n:''.join('HBKD'[int(x,16)/4]+'OAEI'[int(x,16)%4]for x in hex(n)[2:])
```

Chooses the bibi-digit to represent each hex digit based on the patterns in the bibi-digits.

Answer (score 4):

### Javascript (ES6), <s>58</s> <s>53</s> 43 bytes

```
f=n=>n?f(n>>4)+'HBKD'[n/4&3]+'OAEI'[n&3]:''
```

*Saved 10 bytes (no support for n = 0 anymore)*

#### Demo

```js
var f=n=>n?f(n>>4)+'HBKD'[n/4&3]+'OAEI'[n&3]:''

console.log(f(2048));   // -> KOHOHO
console.log(f(156));    // -> KADO
console.log(f(10000));  // -> HEBIHAHO
console.log(f(12));     // -> DO
```

Comment: Can you shorten this now that zero is no longer a requirement?

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 17 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
b⁴d4ị"€“BKDH“AEIO
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=YuKBtGQ04buLIuKCrOKAnEJLREjigJxBRUlP&input=&args=MTU2) or [verify all test cases](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=YuKBtGQ04buLIuKCrOKAnEJLREjigJxBRUlP4oCdCsOH4oKsWQ&input=&args=MjA0OCwgMTU2LCAxMDAwMCwgMTI).

#### How it works

```
b⁴d4ị"€“BKDH“AEIO  Main link. Argument: n

b⁴                 Convert n to base 16.
  d4               Divmod 4; map each base-16 digit k to [k / 4, k % 4].
       “BKDH“AEIO  Yield ["BKDH", "AEIO"].
      €            For each quotient-remainder pair [q, r]:
    ị"               Yield "BKDH"[q] and "AEIO"[r] (1-based indexing).
```

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth, 28 bytes

```
L+?>b15y/b16k@*"HBKD""OAEI"b
```

Defines a function `y`. Basically the same algorithm as my [Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/92123/34543).

Explanation:

```
L                            # Define a function, y, with an argument, b.
  ?>b15                      # If b > 15, then:
       y/b16                 # Call y with b / 16, else:
            k                # The empty string.
 +                           # Append with
              *"HBKD""OAEI"  # The Cartesian product of "HBKD" and "OAEI". Gives all the letter pairs in order
             @             b # Get the b'th number from that list. Because @ in Pyth is modular, we don't need to take b % 16.
```

[Try it here!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/) (The extra two chars at the end is just to call the function)

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, <s>55</s> 51 bytes

A recursive anonymous function:

```
f=->i{(i>15?f[i/16]:'')+'HBKD'[i%16/4]+'OAEI'[i%4]}
```

Call it for example with `f[156]` and it returns `"KADO"`

Answer (score 3):

## PHP ,63 Bytes

contribution by @Titus Thank You

```php
for($n=$argv[1];$n;$n>>=4)$r=HBKD[$n/4&3].OAEI[$n&3].$r;echo$r;
```

72 Bytes works also with zero

```php
do$r=OAEIHBKD[$t*4+($n=&$argv[1])%4].$r;while(($t=!$t)|$n=$n>>2);echo$r;
```

76 Bytes alternative Version

```php
for($i=2*strlen(dechex($n=$argv[1]));$i;)echo HBKDOAEI[$i%2*4+$n/4**--$i%4];
```

Comment: Try this one: `for($n=$argv[1];$n;$n>>=2)$r=HBKDOAEI[$n%4+4*$t=!$t].$r;echo$r;`

Comment: Also: You forgot to golf the curlys from your first version.

Comment: `for($n=$argv[1];$n;$n>>=4)$r=HBKD[$n/4&3].OAEI[$n&3].$r;echo$r;` for also 63 bytes or a port of Arnauld´s answer for 61: `function f($n){return$n?f($n>>4).HBKD[$n/4&3].OAEI[$n&3]:'';}`

Comment: @Titus your first version works not correctly by an input of 1 or 16. Nice I have not realize that zero as input is not longer allowed

Comment: yup, just noticed. it doesnt print the `H` in first place. Take the second one.

Answer (score 3):

## J, <s>35</s> 33 bytes

```
[:,(,/'HBKD',"0/'OAEI'){~16#.inv]
```

Generates the table of bibi-binary values for integers [0, 16), then converts the input *n* to a list of base 16 digits and selects the corresponding bibi-binary name for each hex digit.

Saved 2 bytes thanks to @randomra.

### Usage

```
   ,/'HBKD',"0/'OAEI'
HO
HA
HE
HI
BO
BA
BE
BI
KO
KA
KE
KI
DO
DA
DE
DI
```

This part generates a 16 x 2 array of characters for the bibi-binary name of each hex digit.

```
   f =: [:,(,/'HBKD',."0 1'OAEI'){~16#.inv]
   f 156
KADO
   f 2048
KOHOHO
```

### Explanation

```
,/'HBKD',"0/'OAEI'
  'HBKD'    'OAEI'  Constant char arrays
        ,"0/        Form the table of joining each char with the other
,/                  Join the rows of that table

[:,(,/'HBKD',."0 1'OAEI'){~16#.inv]  Input: n
                                  ]  Identity function, get n
                           16#.inv   Performs the inverse of converting an array of
                                     hex digits meaning it converts a value to a list of
                                     hex digits
   (,/'HBKD',."0 1'OAEI')            Create the bibi-binary names of each hex digit
                         {~          For each hex digit, select its bibi-binary name
[:,                                  Join the names to form a single string and return
```

Comment: `'HBKDOAEI'{~[:(+0 4$~$)4#.inv]`

Answer (score 3):

## Perl, <s>52</s> 51 bytes

Includes +1 for `-p`

Run with the number on STDIN

```
bibi.pl <<< 156
```

`bibi.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -p
1while$\=(<{H,B,K,D}{O,A,E,I}>)[$_%16].$\,$_>>=4}{
```

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, <s>85</s> 83 bytes

```
->x{x.to_s(16).chars.map{|d|"HOHAHEHIBOBABEBIKOKAKEKIDODADEDI"[2*d.to_i(16),2]}*''}
```

Just a quick and simple solution without encoding the string.

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 21 bytes

```
sm@*"HBKD""OAEI"djQ16
```

A program that takes input of an integer from STDIN and prints the result.

[Try it online](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=sm%40%2a%22HBKD%22%22OAEI%22djQ16&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=2048%0A156%0A10000%0A12&debug=0)

**How it works**

```
sm@*"HBKD""OAEI"djQ16  Program. Input: Q
                 jQ16  Yield decimal digits of the base-16 representation of Q as a list
    "HBKD"              Possible first letters
          "OAEI"        Possible second letters
   *                    Cartesian product of those two strings
  @                     Index into the above
 m              d      Map that across the digits list
s                      Concatenate
                       Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 93 bytes

```
$a=HBKDOAEI;$h=dechex($argv[1]);while($h{$i}!=''|$c=hexdec($h{$i++}))echo$a{$c/4}.$a{4+$c%4};
```

This basically leverages the integrated hexadecimal functions and a little trick in the while statement to save on curly braces.

Answer (score 2):

## Java, 224 bytes

```
class N{public static void main(String[]a){String x="0HO1HA2HE3HI4BO5BA6BE7BI8KO9KAaKEbKIcDOdDAeDEfDI";for(int c:Long.toHexString(Long.valueOf(a[0])).toCharArray()){c=x.indexOf(c)+1;System.out.print(x.substring(c++,++c));}}}
```

Using some lookup table trickery
Usage of Long type was to shave off a few bytes compared to Integer

Answer (score 2):

## [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM), 19 [bytes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)

Requires `⎕IO←0` which is default on many systems.

```apl
∊(,'HBKD'∘.,'OAEI')[16⊥⍣¯1⊢⎕]
```

`∊` enlist (make completely flat)

`(`...

`,` the raveled

`'HBKD'∘.,'OAEI'` concatenation table (i.e. all combos)

`)[` indexed by...

`16⊥⍣¯1` the inverse of base-16 to base 10 (i.e. base-10 to base 16) representation

`⊢` of

`⎕` the numeric input

`]`

[TryAPL online!](http://tryapl.org/?a=%u2395IO%u21900%20%u22C4%20f%u2190%7B%u220A%28%2C%27HBKD%27%u2218.%2C%27OAEI%27%29%5B16%u22A5%u2363%AF1%u22A2%u2375%5D%7D%20%u22C4%20f%A82048%20156%2010000%2012&run)

Answer (score 2):

### [CJam](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cjam/), 20 bytes

```
qiGb"HBKD""OAEI"m*f=
```

[Try it online!](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=cU4ve1MvMD06UTsKClFpR2IiSEJLRCIiT0FFSSJtKmY9Cgpdbn0v&input=MjA0OCAtPiBLT0hPSE8KMTU2IC0-IEtBRE8KMTAwMDAgLT4gSEVCSUhBSE8KMTIgLT4gRE8) (As a linefeed-separated test suite.)

#### Explanation

```
qi      e# Read input and convert to integer.
Gb      e# Get hexadecimal digits.
"HBKD"  e# Push this string.
"OAEI"  e# Push this string.
m*      e# Cartesian product, yields ["HO" "HA" "HE" "HI" "BO" ... "DE" "DI"].
f=      e# For each digit, select the corresponding syllable.
```

Answer (score 1):

## Lua, 196 Bytes

```
function(n)s=""t={"H","B","K","D"}p={"O","A","E","I"}while n>0 do s=n%4 ..s n=math.floor(n/4)end s=("0"):rep(#s%2)..s o=nil return s:gsub(".",function(s)o=not o return o and t[s+1]or p[s+1]end)end
```

Lua is annoying for this sort of a task, as it doesn't per default contain a hex or binary conversion method. Most of the flesh is converting it to base 4. After that we force a 0 behind it if we need to using `s=("0"):rep(#s%2)`, then we using gsub replace all the didgets with with their BIBI counterpart.

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://bitbucket.org/ngn/k), <s>30</s> 27 bytes

```
,/(,/"HBKD",/:\:"OAEI")@16\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/z/NSkdfQ0dfycPJ20VJR98qxkrJ39HVU0nTwdAs5n@aupGBiYWCoamZgqEBECgYGv0HAA)

Quite similar to the J solution by @miles and the APL solution by @adám.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 13 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
s"HBKD"ï"OAEI
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=cyJIQktEIu8iT0FFSQ&input=MTAwMDA)

Or, with string compression:

```
s`baki`ó rï
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=c2CXYmFrgmlg8yBy7w&input=MTAwMDA)

Comment: what is this sorcery

Comment: Just a straightforward custom base conversion, @Razetime.

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 76 bytes

```hs
(until(\x->x<="HO"||x>="HP")(drop 2)`map`mapM id([1..8]>>["HBKD","OAEI"])!!)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfZhvzX6M0ryQzRyOmQteuwsZWycNfqaamwg7ICFDS1Egpyi9QMNJMyE0sAGFfhcwUjWhDPT2LWDu7aCUPJ28XJR0lf0dXT6VYTUVFzf@5iZl5tgVFmXklKkDlCmkK0QY6hjpGBiYWOoamZjqGBkCgY2gU@/9fclpOYnrxf93kggIA)

Since the input is guaranteed to fit in 32 bits, we can generate a list of all \$16^8 = 2^{32}\$ strings and index into it, after removing `HO` (zeroes) from the start.

(Haskell's Prelude has no good tools for base conversion, but Cartesian products are real easy with `mapM`.)

To strip superfluous `HO`s from the start of each string, we `drop 2` characters from the front `until` the string either *equals* `HO` (0), or does not start with `HO`.

The obvious way to write this is `x=="HO"||take 2x/="HO"`, but `x<="HO"||x>="HP"` is a little shorter.

Comment: Since the challenge says that the input is positive, it looks like you don't have to special-case 0.

Comment: Hmm, I'll leave it as is, because some of the other answers go out of their way to handle 0, and it seemed to have been unclear at some point in the history of the challenge looking at the comment; and I like my `<=` `>=` trick better than I like saving some bytes with `until((/="HO").take 2)`

Comment: Here's a way to handle the `HO`-removal by defining it as a separate function: [TIO](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfZhvzX0NRUVOl0EbFLjexwFchM0Uj2lBPzyLWzi5aycPJ20VJR8nf0dVTKVaTq1BD3UPdSt1f3SrZqkTTtlADRHEVKlTYVvzPTczMsy0oyswrUQGao5CmEG2gY6hjZGBioWNoaqZjaAAEOoZGsf//JaflJKYX/9dNLigAAA "Haskell – Try It Online") It may be possible to shorten the first line here, perhaps by reordering it to avoid the `map`. Though now that I think about it, it might be best to just calculate how many characters to drop from the size-16 string based on `n`, without looking at the resulting string.

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 50 bytes

```hs
(l!!)
l=[]:tail[x++[a,b]|x<-l,a<-"HBKD",b<-"OAEI"]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfZhvzXyNHUVGTK8c2OtaqJDEzJ7pCWzs6UScptqbCRjdHJ9FGV8nDydtFSScJyPJ3dPVUiv2fm5iZp2CrUFCUmVeioKKQm1igkKYQbWRgYqGjYGhqBiQMgABIGcX@/5eclpOYXvxfN7mgAAA)

Recursively defines the infinite list `l` of all encoded numbers starting from 0.

---

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 54 bytes

```hs
f n=mapM id([1|i<-[0..8],16^i<=n]>>["HBKD","OAEI"])!!n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00hzzY3scBXITNFI9qwJtNGN9pAT88iVsfQLC7TxjYv1s4uWsnDydtFSUfJ39HVUylWU1Ex739uYmaegq1CQVFmXomCigLQBIU0hWgDHQVDHQUjIAnCpmZAtoGJBZBpAASx//8lp@Ukphf/100uKAAA)

Based off of [Lynn's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214538/20260). The new idea is to avoid leading "zeroes" (`HO`'s) by predicting the number of digits in advance and only generating that many copies for `mapM`. A number has one digit in base 16 for each number in `1,16,256,4096,...` that is no greater than it. This gives the empty string for zero, but we could change it to `HO` like this:

**56 bytes**

```hs
f n=mapM id(0:[1|i<-[1..8],16^i<=n]>>["HBKD","OAEI"])!!n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00hzzY3scBXITNFw8Aq2rAm00Y32lBPzyJWx9AsLtPGNi/Wzi5aycPJ20VJR8nf0dVTKVZTUTHvf25iZp6CrUJBUWZeiYKKAtAMhTSFaAMdBUMdBSMgCcKmZkC2gYkFkGkABLH//yWn5SSmF//XTS4oAAA)

A variant where we compute the number of digits directly:

**60 bytes**

```hs
f n=mapM id([0..until(\i->16^i>n)(+1)0]>>["HBKD","OAEI"])!!n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYzBCsIwEAV/ZRs8NJiWRLR4aUBRUET8gJhCqEYX0yXY@vvG@GCGOb2nG1/3EFLyQO3g4hnwVhpZ1x@aMJRXrLRqOtTEy7ni0mpt2GF72jHBLpv9kVleFJQGhwQtxDfSBDPIP@DBSAFKwCL7z6rJLZfrnDLPpm/vg3uMqepj/AE)

---

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 54 bytes

```hs
f 0=""
f n=f(div n 16)++mapM id[cycle"HBKD","OAEI"]!!n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P03BwFZJiStNIc82TSMls0whT8HQTFNbOzexwFchMyU6uTI5J1XJw8nbRUlHyd/R1VMpVlEx739uYmaegq1CQVFmXomCigJQtUKaQrSBjoKhjoIRkARhUzMg28DEAsg0AILY//@S03IS04v/6yYXFAAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Chip](https://github.com/Phlarx/chip), 174 bytes

```
 z---.
!+ZZZ^~s
Axxx])~-vv/c
Ex]xx' ,x]/b
Bxxx])~^}~/d
Fx]xx'g*-}^a
Cxx])v]--/c
G]xx'>x~v/d
Dxx])x+-]/a
H]xx'`}--/b
 )x)-----'
Axx].zv~S
Bxx]+^'
Cxx]<
Dxx]<
E]v-'
F]<
G]<
H]'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RVBNa8MwDL3rV2ilw81S2WynHkJhXZP2tsNuAYclabsGRmcaY7Sy@K9ndnaYQEK89/TZ1P15bGuLa7TH3sr23BnMMhT5ayFGvBGRhLu0LMvK9/DMzDrx5JxqIWfNLHDJWjWw@WOqwasDFBPz8UBDVcNLJJwmCiW7iK/ZuyDaRpxT0qqGfcTfh6BpABNOKJqI47S8Of8W2@u0ElOzbCrNINcuaIqQ7YLvtRjDzgDm2l3sCWf3csUznC/icfNT93lM8AeZD0hXJBNy9WWsivdOQZpvJPf/hPHx6Rc) TIO includes a Bash wrapper that converts an integer string to an actual 32-bit integer value.

The top half prints out the letters corresponding to the binary data, once the bottom half has detected that we've reached the interesting data (in other words, we skip leading zeroes. To print all leading zeroes, remove the second line that starts with `A` and down.

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 206 bytes

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
int main(){int a=0;char c;while(read(0,&c,1)){a*=10;a+=c-'0';}c=8;while(c--)if(a&15<<c*4)break;if(c!=7)c++;while(c--)printf("%c%c","HBKD"[a>>c*4+2&3],"OAEI"[a>>c*4&3]);}
```

Uses as requested input, no check done on read return.

```c
int a=0;char c;                                                                                                                                               // declares accumilator and input char
               while(read(0,&c,1)){a*=10;a+=c-'0';}                                                                                                           // read input in accumulator
                                                   c=8;while(c--)if(a&15<<c*4)break;if(c!=7)c++;                                                              // goto first not null byte
                                                                                                while(c--)printf("%c%c",                                      // print for each byte
                                                                                                                        "HBKD"[a>>c*4+2&3],                   // fetching right consonant
                                                                                                                                           "OAEI"[a>>c*4&3]); // fetching right vowel
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc3fCoIwFAbw@57CFuqmLmZ/KJgTioKiix4gulhHzZFZmNKF@OxrQUXn6uPH93GAngG0HqgSiiZJo0edqNswj3s/aUpl8E2qrK2rVCUm7TtKwTjksrKAP3NVpLhKZYJZ4EAQEtJKT4SMS18AdZnLOxDzTw8oJSrD0gmnUQTehJzM8sINQV/MCPj@X/FemV8ZRjbYgAK0We5W6CDj2Oz8kTM@Bmi/WG@/ZIDwTuuQmXsB)

Comment: Hi ceilingcat, what a good idea, I'll integrate it soon ;-)

Comment: [137 bytes](https://tio.run/##NYpBCsIwEADf0kBDtkmg0YqVNAVFQfHgA8TDsrYa0CpB8CC@PUbEOc4M6RNRjGiv6AdB8Hqe/aUTocOjKBUnZQBQulmBknRV2/4WBLnaktZFJpCbSdNQUYGFX5KOMjf9Zgv34IdHL1hOOTHF1ovtku2xbdMvR3x8UGw3X23@Kgmw7xhNmfgA "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 20 bytes

```
ṁ!ṙ1*"HBKD""OAEI"B16
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//@HORsWHO2caail5OHm7KCn5O7p6KjkZmv3//9/IwMQCAA)

Similiar to the APL answer.

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 22 bytes

```
ṁz!e"BKDH""AEIO"m‰4B16
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//@HOxirFVCUnbxcPJSVHV09/pdxHDRtMnAzN/v//b2RgYgEA)

Idea from Dennis' answer.